# LXML for windows 7 (For scrapy)

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, lxml

I am trying to install lxml fro windows 7 from exe given at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5#downloads. I am getting this error saying python 2.7 is missing in registry. I have tried checking in the registry and its very much there. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right version of lxml for the version of Pythonyou have installed. For example, for Python 2.7 32-bit, you need to install `lxml-3.3.5.win32-py2.7.exe`. If you have Python 2.7 64-bit, then you'll need to install `lxml-3.3.5.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`.

If that doesn't work, reinstall Python as it probably isn't installed correctly.